QGIS Layer Styling: Stop further styling if condition true?
Is it somehow possible to stop further styling of an feature if the condition is true? So that the feature gets set aside when the next Layer Styling row is read. This is an option in eg FME and Mapublisher, and imho super useful.
Out of the box QGIS stylings get stacked on top of each other or erase those in earlier rows unless I use a bunch of inconvenient IS NOT(s).
Updated with an example:
Two features and their table:
Feature 1: att1 = A, att2 = B, att3 = C
Feature 2: att1 = NULL, att2 = B, att3 = NULL

The first row in the Layer Styler formats att1 = A. And there I want it to stop styling Feature 1 further.
Beacuse in the next row of the Layer Styler att2 = B gets its appearance. This means that feature 1 will get styled twice, unless I ad IS NOT att1 = A.
This is just a very basic example, the tables in my projects are a lot more complex.
Other maping softwares like FME, and Mapublisher have this option built in, so I wanted to see if it could be done in QGIS also.

This is unclear could you describe in more detail what you want to do, maybe by providing some exemple ?

Please provide images comparing what you currently have and what you're trying to achieve, as well as some example data.

Using your example, I would use rule-based symbology and use the Coalesce function to return the first non-null value in your attributes, e.g.:
 coalesce("att1", "att2", "att3") = 'A'



Use QGIS expressions with case ... when conditions: it "evaluates a series of conditions and return a result for the first condition met.", so it will not re-assign another style if the first condition is met.
You can use this expression to define one aspect of the style (e.g. color) with date driven override (see example below/screenshot).
For more complex examples with different aspects of the style, to each when statement add a different category (like numbers: 1, 2, 3, ...) to the then (instead of colors, as in the example below). Then use categorized style and for the value, add this expression. You can than style each category individually.
The syntax looks like this:
CASE 
WHEN att1 = 'A' then 'red'
when att2 = 'B' then 'blue'
when att3 = 'C' then 'green'
else 'gray'
end

The expression above, used for data driven override of the feature color:

Verios 2 with categorized style:

